# Exotic Function with Log Property

Tags: logarithms, examples-counterexamples

It's a well known result that, with some additional assumptions (often continuity or monotonicity), all functions $f : \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$ are constant multiples of $\log$.

It occurs to me that I've never seen a function which shows the necessity of the additional assumptions. Is there a function which satisfies $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$ but is *not* a constant multiple of $\log$?

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492 or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (many) exotic solutions $\alpha\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ of the functional equation $\alpha(x+y)=\alpha(x)+\alpha(y)$. Indeed, $\alpha$ is a solutions iff it is linear with respect to the structure of a rational vector space. The exotic ones are exactly those sich are not multiples of the identity.

So $f:=\alpha\circ\log$ is an exotic *logarithmic* function if $\alpha$ is as above.

*Edit:* It can be seen quite easily that $f$ satisfies the equation (1) $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$ if $\alpha:=f\circ\exp$ satisfies (2) $\alpha(x+y)=\alpha(x)+\alpha(y)$. Thus $f$ solves (1) iff $f=\alpha\circ\log$ with some $\alpha$ satisfying (2).

Comment: This combined with kimchi lover's comment answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: Based on the links, it seems like there are no explicit constructions of such an $\alpha$. Is that right? Is it known that such $\alpha$ can only be exhibited non-constructively?

Comment: The construction of $\alpha$ depends in the existence of a base of $\mathbb{R}$ considered as a vector space over the field of rational numbers.

Comment: Solovay showed that it is consistent with Zermelo-Frankel set theory (without the Axiom of Choice) that all subsets of $\mathbb R$ are Lebesgue measurable.  These "exotic logarithms" are non-measurable functions.  Thus without using some form of the Axiom of Choice, either you can't construct $f$ or you can't prove it satisfies the requirements.